# Release Runtime Error VS2008 - Problem Specific

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static-libraries

I have a code piece that works perfectly fine when I execute it in Debug mode however it gives a runtime error when I execute it in Release mode. It is a console based application and I have added an external static library.

The problem does not lie in the piece of code since it crashes only when it using the library. Please keep in mind it works perfectly fine in Debug mode.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: without the piece of your code that is provoking the crash, and the exact runtime error, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Indeed, please inform us what the runtime error is. And do you receive any compile time warnings?

Comment: you should find out where it crashes (with printfs, sleep functions, file writing or whatever method you have - even debug is possible in Release). After you found the place you put the question...

Comment: Compile time warnings which I get are these: 1-warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '.\Bitmap.lib 2-warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' 3-warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library But I only get the first one in Debug mode

it crashes when I try to use a method belonging to the static library which I use. It gives the following error: A buffer overrun has occurred in hw4-13313-3.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state.

Comment: @JohanR has answered your question accurately.  The key line from this warning message is `LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library` which means some object file specifies that it was built using DEBUG CRT instead of RELEASE CRT.

Answer (score 1):

Just because it works okay in debug mode doesn't mean there isn't an issue. Changing to release mode removes buffer padding, turns on optomisations etc. ...so it's not exactly the same piece of code.

Have you tried sticking some break points in to see how far it gets and to try and diagnose where it's crashing out?

What library are you calling? Are you passing it any buffers? have you initialised it properly?

Comment: It crashes when I try to use a method  belonging to the static library which I use. It gives the following error: A buffer overrun has occurred in hw4-13313-3.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state.

Comment: Compile time warnings which I get are these:
1-warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '.\Bitmap.lib
2-warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF'
3-warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

But I only get the first one in Debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Could it possibly be the case that the library you're using has a debug version as well as a release version? and you are perhaps linking the debug version in both builds?

Comment: This is the answer to his question.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you get the error "defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs;" I would not be surprised if your problems might be caused by linking against different versions of the runtime. 
Make sure that all exe/libs/dll files are linked against the same version (either static or dynamic) of the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you've got a crash due to a buffer overrun, so use a tool such as [gflags](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2010/06/22/detecting-heap-corruption-using-gflags-and-dumps.aspx) to diagnose where this buffer overrun is happening.

There are many cases where code works absolutely fine in a debug build but crashes in a release build. The most common explanations are:

- Execution or class sizes may be different because of code inside `#ifdef _DEBUG` sections
- On Windows, uninitialised variables are initialised to zero in a debug build.  In a release build they will be random